# Symfony 5 inject service by alias

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5

I have a service called:

```
<?php
class CustomService
{
    private $string;
    private $service1;
    private $service2;
    
    public function __construct($string, Service1 $service1, Service2 $service2)
    {
        $this->string = $string;
        $this->service1 = $service1;
        $this->service2 = $service2;
    }

    //Custom functions
}
```

The $string parameter is a string that can change its value.

I want to call this service from other services, but is there a way to define the ´CustomService´ in my services.yaml with some kind of alias?

```
service:
    App\Service\CustomService:
        alias: preService1
        arguments:
            $string: 'ABCD'
    
    App\Service\CustomService:
        alias: preService2
        arguments:
            $string: 'EFGH'
```

And inject one of the services defined by alias in another service:

```
<?php
class PurchaseService
{
    public function __construct(CustomService $preService1)
    {
        //Here $preService1->string must be 'ABCD'
    }
    
    //Or in other functions in this service $preService1->string must be 'ABCD'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just had a very similar issue and this is the solution I got to. You need to inject the alias of your CustomService into PurchasService.

It is not necessary to disable automatic wiring, so additional arguments will still be autowired.

```
service:
    app.service.pre_service1:
        class: App\Service\CustomService
        arguments:
            $string: 'ABCD'
            
    app.service.pre_service2:
        class: App\Service\CustomService
        arguments:
            $string: 'EFGH'
            
    app.service.purchase_service:
        class: App\Service\PurchaseService
        arguments:
            $preService1: '@app.service.pre_service1'
            
    App\Service\PurchaseService:
        alias: app.service.purchase_service
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#explicitly-configuring-services-and-arguments) you can create aliases:

```
#service.yml

preService1:
    class: App\Service\CustomService:
    autowire: false
    arguments:
        $string: 'ABCD'

preService2:
    class: App\Service\CustomService:
    autowire: false
    arguments:
        $string: 'EFGH'
```

Comment: `autowire: false` is redundant. Moreover in this case you must set other dependecies (Service1 and Service2)

Comment: @BoShurik It's not so much that autowire: false is redundant as it just wrong.  Keeping it true (the default) means that the additional arguments could be autowired.  It still does not completely answer the question in that PurchaseService also need a service definition.  Kind of wish this was not a drive by question.  With a bit of feedback an actual answer could have been made.  Oh well.

Answer (score -2):

I can't comment so I post this as an answer.
Unless I missed something, you have different ways of looking at this.
Either you can extend a base class to implement the string feature (or use a Trait if the $string is the only need you have).

You could also use a Factory return the service you need

```
Factory::getCustomService($string) {
  $customService = createCustomService();
  $customService->setString($string);
  return $customService;
}
```

I am not sure how you would use this later on, but it seems a bit odd at first glance, so I would recommend either a Factory or using inheritance if you do not wish to set this variable after instantiating the service.

The simplest couuld be:

```
<?php
class PurchaseService
{
    public function __construct(CustomService $preService1)
    {
        $preService1->setString ('ABCD');
    }
    
    //Or in other functions in this service $preService1->string must be 'ABCD'
}
```

Comment: Ok, I will give it a try

Comment: The fact that you can't comment does not mean you should post off-topic answers.  Symfony has their way of doing things.  Hopefully the op won't waste much time on your approach.

Comment: @Cerad I am happy to debate over constructive discussion. My approach would work with Symfony so I am curious to know wh at would be a better approach so I can also improve. What would be your solution? I read the autowiring false solution which would work as well indeed but you then still need to call two different services. I guess it's down to personal preferences but I am honestly happy to get a better understanding of your thinking

Comment: Your answer overlooks the additional arguments need to create the service.  It also overlooks the possibility of using a Symfony service locator.  Your approach basically disregards the entire Symfony DI container which is what the question is all about.  But who knows.  Maybe it will get accepted.

Comment: Well, I get your point. Faced with a similar situation I would probably use the autowiring and inheritance so that DI is maintained. That would also mean less yaml config. What is the .Ain advantage of autowiring false in your view here (genuine question).

Comment: Are you asking about the autowire: false in the other answer? No idea why they did that.  I didn't even notice when I skimmed it.  What they posted won't work. Discussions like this are not a good fit for stackoverflow.  Post something on Reddit Symfony if you want.